# Converting Data from http request from JSON Dictionary of Dictionaries into one Array of Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

When Running my http request I get returned the data in the following way.

I am requesting as follows

```
    do {
        if let file = URL(string: "https://myhttprequest....") {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let object = json as? [String: Any] {
                // json is a dictionary
                print(object)
            } else {
                print("JSON is invalid")
            }
        } else {
            print("no file")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

The http request shows like this for example

```
{"created":[{"id":"-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK","caption":"Cool watch bro ","creationDate":1546442937.5934439,"imageHeight":1000,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."}],"reshared":[{"id":"-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK","caption":"Cool watch bro ","creationDate":1546442937.5934439,"imageHeight":1000,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."}]}
```

I want to be able to put the value of object["created"] and object["reshared"] together to have one array of two dictionaries [[caption:"", creationDate:""...],[caption:"", creationDate:""...]]

I have tried by accessing them individually like object["created"] but its not of type dictionary and I cant seem to figure out how to get it to be one.

UPDATE: So I am now doing the following 
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://us-central1-flashtrend-bdcd3.cloudfunctions.net/getFeed/\(uid)")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let firstData = data else { return }
        let jsonStr = String(data: firstData, encoding: .utf8)!
        guard  let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return
        }
        do {
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                return
            }
            guard let created = json["created"], let reshared = json["reshared"] else {
                return
            }
            let result = [created, reshared]

            print(result)

        } catch  {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

But when i print it looks weird

```
[<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600002de2290>(
{
    caption = "Cool watch bro ";
    creationDate = "1546442937.593444";
    id = "-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK";
    imageHeight = 1000;
    imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flashtrend-bdcd3.appspot.com/o/posts%2FE346E4B7-31D8-4E9E-89F2-DA7C426C0537?alt=media&token=4936ce58-64bb-4d5a-b913-c3b87705614f";
    imageWidth = 750;
    swipes = 0;
    userid = U9097gARoXOus96vT1uBHAcNPs03;
    views = 1;
}
)
, <__NSArray0 0x600002df40c0>(

)
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the http request result to `json string`, sample code for you as follow, works fine on my xcode:

```
let jsonStr = "{\"created\":{\"caption\":\"Cool watch bro \",\"creationDate\":\"1546442937.593444\",\"id\":\"-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK\",\"imageHeight\":1000,\"imageUrl\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flashtrend-bdcd3.appspot.com/o/posts/E346E4B7-31D8-4E9E-89F2-DA7C426C0537?alt:media&token:4936ce58-64bb-4d5a-b913-c3b87705614f\",\"imageWidth\":750,\"swipes\":0,\"userid\":\"U9097gARoXOus96vT1uBHAcNPs03\",\"views\":1},\"reshared\":{\"caption \":\"Cool watch bro\",\"creationDate \":\"1546442937.593444\",\"id \":\"-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK \",\"imageHeight\":1000,\"imageUrl\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flashtrend-bdcd3.appspot.com/o/posts/E346E4B7-31D8-4E9E-89F2-DA7C426C0537?alt:media&token:4936ce58-64bb-4d5a-b913-c3b87705614f\",\"imageWidth\":750,\"swipes\":0,\"userid\":\"U9097gARoXOus96vT1uBHAcNPs03\",\"views\":1}}"

guard  let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return
}
do {
    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }
    guard let created = json["created"], let reshared = json["reshared"] else {
        return
    }
    let result = [created, reshared]
    print(result)
} catch  {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: This is working but how would I go about forming that json String properly

Comment: dont you want to put the value of object["created"] and object["reshared"] together to have one array of two dictionaries, the `json string` is the data that get from  your back-end.

Comment: I do, but Im not sure how to create the jsonStr from my http request

Comment: please  show the response data from your http request.

Comment: How would I make the http request to get the Json string

Comment: `guard  let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) else` will never fail. `Data(jsonStr.utf8)`. Btw `options: [] ` is the default value (can be omitted). And `print(error)` localizedDescription is redundant.

Comment: @LeoDabus how do I create the jsonStr though?

Comment: you can download it asynchronously using `URLSession` method `dataTask(with: URL)` (don't use `Data(contentsOf: URL)`
 for non local resources).  In the completion handler closure just unwrap the data returned by your server API `guard let data = data, let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }`

Comment: Btw I would use `Codable` protocol and use `JSONDecoder` to structure your JSON data when parsing it.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have updated with my current results, any idea where I went wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186117/discussion-between-user6520705-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @user6520705 `let jsonData = Data("""
{"created":[{"id":"-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK","caption":"Cool watch bro ","creationDate":1546442937.5934439,"imageHeight":1000,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."}],"reshared":[{"id":"-LVEAdIk2KwDmxBj25pK","caption":"Cool watch bro ","creationDate":1546442937.5934439,"imageHeight":1000,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."}]}
""".utf8)`

Comment: `struct Root: Codable {
    let created: [Created]
    let reshared: [Created]
}

struct Created: Codable {
    let id: String
    let caption: String
    let creationDate: Double
    let imageHeight: Int
    let imageUrl: String
}
do {
     let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
    print(root.created.first?.id)
} catch {
    print(error)
}`